# vagrant virtualbox cannot make a POST request to a local rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, virtualbox, virtualhost

I have a rails app running locally on port 3000.

From an app on [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/):

```
Requests::post( 'http://0.0.0.0:3000', $header, $payload );
```

Response:

```
'Cannot connect to host'
```

Note that when I run the same code out of the context of Vagrant, it works perfectly.
Note also that Vagrant has no problem POSTing to a version of the same rails app when it is not hosted locally.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to call the API using the IP Address, ie:

```
http://50.19.293.12:3000
```